# VB.net read large XML file in parallel

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlreader

Story:
I have a big XML file of about 70+ GB I need to parse to my database once a week. Currently I have a working parser in vb.net using the XmlReader. I'm currently maxing out at about 5.000 nodes / sec and with >10.000.000 nodes and increasing, it's taking a while to complete. The program is running on my own server in the garage with an ordinary SSD. I assumed the limiting factor was the SSD, so I recently upgraded to a Samsung EVO 970 M.2 SSD with 6x more read/write speeds. The problem is that I didn't see any noticeable performance increase. Looking back it's probably obvious that the bottleneck is somewhere else..

Idea: 
I started investigating. I implemented 2 separate threads, each reading the file from the beginning, a few seconds apart. Each thread still read and processed about 5.000 nodes / sec so effectively I was processing 10.000 nodes / sec now. However the problem was that I was parsing every node twice, which kind of eliminated the purpose. Next idea was for one thread to read + process the data from the beginning. The second thread would also read from the beginning of the file, however this thread would simply skip the first half of the file, before it would start processing the data. Using the XMLReader.ReadToNextSibling() I was able to "skip" 6.250.000 nodes at a rate of 10.000 nodes / sec. This essentially means the first thread would have processed about 3.125.000 nodes by the time the second thread finishes the "skip" and starts parsing from 6.250.000 nodes in. At this point there would be about 6.875.000 nodes left split between the 2 threads and the parser would from this point on process about 10.000 nodes / sec. Essentially I would like to increase the threads until I reach another bottleneck. This approach is very primitive and "wastes" a lot of time reading and skipping the same nodes. I tried XmlReaderSettings.LineNumberOffset, however I couldn't get this to work and it always seemed to read from the beginning no matter the offset.

```
Dim settings = New Xml.XmlReaderSettings()
settings.LineNumberOffset = 100000

Dim XMLReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create("C:\largexml.xml", settings)
```

Question:
Any ideas on parallel read of large XML files and possible bottlenecks or optimizations. Is there a faster way to "skip" n elements than using ReadToNextSibling like this?

```
Dim Count As Integer = 0
While Count < 5000000
   XMLReader.ReadToNextSibling("ns")
   Count += 1
End While
```

I've made som calculations of the current "skip" solution, and since I have to read the same data in each thread, then the speed bonus is asymptotic to +50% speed boost. Here is the graph in case anyone has the same problem and is considering a similar naive solution. Here is the expected performance increase / thread.

[image]

Comment: So does node equate to db record? Are you reading a node and sending results directly to the DB?  How are the records sent (sequential inserts or bulk copy)?  What DB are are you using?

Comment: All the test here is without the parse to the database. In production I'm saving 5.000 nodes from the XML file in a DataTable and then I'm bulk inserting that to the MSSQL server. This however happens pretty much instantly, and in my current test i simply insert 5.000 rows to the DataTable in my application and then clears it without pushing to the database. So the current bottleneck isn't with the database.

Comment: Have you played with increasing the [StreamReader's buffer size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_) from the default 128 characters to say 1024 characters to see if that helps?  You could also try increaing the underlying stream's buffer as well.

Comment: @TnTinMn That's not the default, it's the minimum allowed. The default is `1024` bytes for the StreamReader buffer (`4096` for a File Stream Buffer), but `4096` for the XMLReader, or `8192`, depending on the Stream size.

Comment: @Jimi, thanks for prompting me to check on that.  It looks like I should have checked the source code instead of doc that I referenced.  In any case, it may still be helpful to supply a StreamReader to XMLReader. Create that has a larger buffersize. So instead of the 8192 max default you stated, perhaps use twice that value.  They gave us that ability for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

See if following code is faster.  The XElement.ReadFrom() reads a sibling so it only reads an item once. Check in Task Manager the memory usage as code runs.  If you run out of memory than swap space on disk is used which can really slow down an app.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "C:\largexml.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME)
        While Not reader.EOF
            If reader.Name <> "ns" Then
                reader.ReadToFollowing("ns")
            End If
            If Not reader.EOF Then
                Dim ns As XElement = XElement.ReadFrom(reader)
            End If
        End While

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Great suggestion. I'll try this implementation tomorrow and report the results. My current solution had a constant memory use of a few mb. I would like to be able to utilize more of the 16 GB ram currently on the server. Ideally it would load the file into memory in chunks og lets say 8hb, but I'm desperate at this point, and if ram is the problem, then I would be willing to upgrade my server with 128 GB. Then the entire file should in theory be able to be loaded into memory at once.

Comment: I've used this code a lot on huge xml where I was getting Out Of Memory Exceptions.  One case had to parse a GML graphical file where the siblings were so large I still had Out of Memory exceptions and had to read in smaller pieces.